# webpack - output.filename error

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-3

I know this is a common question for webpack; it's really hard to debug something if it won't give you any information about the cause or location of the error.

I'm getting the error:

```
Error: 'output.filename' is required, either in config file or as --output-filename
```

I know it has to do with a syntax error somewhere, but I'm too new to webpack to figure it out.

Here's my config file. It's called "webpack.config.js" in the root folder (i.e. the folder in which I initially ran: npm init).

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require("path");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin")
const RewriteImportPlugin = require("less-plugin-rewrite-import");

const root_dir = path.resolve(__dirname)
const src_dir = path.resolve(__dirname, "webpack_src")
const build_dir = path.resolve(__dirname, "webpack_bin")
const node_mod_dir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules');
const extractLESS = new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css');

const config = {
  entry: {
    index: path.resolve(src_dir, 'index.js')
  },
  output: {
    path: build_dir,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [root_dir, 'node_modules'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        test: /\.(js)$/
      },
      {
        use: extractLESS.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: [
            'css-loader',
            {
              loader: 'less-loader',
              options: {
                paths: [root_dir, node_mod_dir],
                plugins: [
                  new RewriteImportPlugin({
                    paths: {
                      '../../theme.config': __dirname + '/semantic_ui/theme.config',
                    }
                  })
                ]
              }
            }]
        }),
        test: /\.less$/
      },
      {
        use: ['file-loader'],
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|woff|svg|eot|ttf|woff2)$/
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    extractLESS,
    new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin()
  ]
};

module.exports = {
  config
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're exporting `module.exports = { config }`, which means that you are exporting an object with one property, namely `config`, but webpack expects the object to be your entire config. Webpack requires `output.filename`, whereas you only provide `config.output.filename`.

The export should be your `config`:

```
module.exports = config;
```

Comment: That's it! I had seen another thread with a lot of similar syntactical suggestions, but none of them mentioned the bracket issue.

Comment: I (incorrectly) though either way was acceptable - with brackets or without. 

Also, if anyone wants  a non-Frankenstein (I've already corrected a few more things from my snippet above) example of how to implement semantic-ui-react with semantic-ui-less themes, I would use this blog, which links to git examples: [neekey](http://neekey.net/2016/12/09/integrate-react-webpack-with-semantic-ui-and-theming/)